# Retrieving iOS Simulator DerivedData App Container ID

Tags: ios, bash, jenkins, xctest, fastlane

I'm writing a framework around **XCTest** for UI automation which stores several report files and logs into the Simulator app's sandboxed Documents folder.

Now I need to find a way to retrieve the path to this folder *outside* of the app for running and processing the report files in **Jenkins**.

Does anyone know of a method to know the path via bash? I'm running the UI tests with **Fastlane**.

The folder where the files are stored is something like:

```
/Users/myself/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/089CCA15-5CE2-42B6-8F95-2A1934AD81E0/data/Containers/Data/Application/0BA977B9-E898-47C0-BA2E-1BC74144D138/Documents
```

In essence the only info that is needed is the app container ID used here (0BA977B9-E898-47C0-BA2E-1BC74144D138) since this is the only part that changes frequently. Does anyone know if there are any facilities to retrieve this bit of information via bash?

Answer (score 0):

We are making same thing and we are currently stopped at just printing folder to logs and use grep to retrieve it. That guarantee that the folder will be exactly of the simulator that was used to test the app.